# IE 11 cookies not persisting

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I have a weird issue that's happening with IE 11. I have a login that will redirect user to `/home` when they are successfully logged in. If close IE 11, and I go directly back to `/home` I'm successfully logged in, but the `jessionid` cookie has changed. It is preventing me from completing another action directly following a successful login. However, I did notice that if I do the exact same thing two more times, then on the third attempt, the `jession` cookie will persist.

I've tried this same thing in IE 10, and I ran into no issues whatsoever. Also, I'm not noticing this issue anywhere else.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**  To make this even more difficult to track down, today, I came in and I was playing around with it and for whatever reason, I can't reproduce the issue no matter what I do. Regardless of how I'm testing it every time I open the browser and navigate back to `/home` I'm getting the `jesssionid` that I expect.

Comment: My first guess would be to check if there are any issues noted in the programming language or software this website is built in.

Comment: That is what I did initially, however, since it is working everywhere else, I'm thinking that it is an issues specifically with IE 11. But I'm trying to confirm my suspicion.

Comment: There is a saying that 75% of development time is spent cursing IE for not working only on that browser. : )